# How to force line buffering for python 3.6.7?

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I use "stdbuf -oL" to force line buffering when running commands on Ubuntu. This works for Python 2.7, but does not seem to work for Python 3.6.7:

```
# test_buf.py
import time 
for i in range(10):  
  print('a')  
  time.sleep(1)
```

I run the command: stdbuf -oL python test_buf.py > output.txt

When running with Python 3.6.7 the file output.txt updated only after the interpreter exists. When running with Python 2.7 output.txt is updated with every line written.
1. Any idea why stdbuf does not work with Python 3.6.7?
2. Any other alternative to force line buffering (not from within the Python process)?

Comment: `unbuffer python test_buf.py > /tmp/output.txt` followed by `watch -n 1 tail /tmp/output.txt` works on Ubuntu 18.04. See [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/3330).

Comment: On the [difference between unbuffer and stdbuf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97294/3330).

Comment: `python -u test_buf.py > /tmp/output.txt` [is another alternative](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/182537/3330).

Comment: Will -u not result in totally unbuffered output? I find https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3116/ somewhat unclear.

Comment: Oops, yes. [`-u` forces stdin, stdout, and stderr to be totally unbuffered](https://linux.die.net/man/1/python).

Comment: Actually, testing locally with -u resulted in line_buffered output, so that's probably the right course of action.